# Using Kubernetes and CRDs as a database and then searching

Tags: kubernetes, relational-database, kubernetes-custom-resources

My background is from a more traditional LAMP stack but with a strong RDBMS orientation, so to me everything in life (including grocery list) is a potential relational database.

My company is now fully committed to using golang and kubernetes `CRD`s as the equivalent to a database that has some relational aspects like one-many, but some NOSQL aspects as well for the records.

That's great, but how do you search anything other than the root UUID or unique name?  in Oracle or MySQL you can do:

```
SELECT (field1, field2, .. [improves performance to select only needed fields]
FROM my_table WHERE field3 > 100
ORDER BY field4, field5
```

Is all that out the window at this point?  And beyond that, are joins or particularly left joins no longer available?  I have been searching for information on this and so far haven't found anything.

I appreciate both specifics as well as usage strategy.  Thanks.

Comment: usage strategy: don't.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my decision.  I may see if I can talk management into some type of SQLite implementation that syncs less-critical data and fields into true tables which can then be joined.  But yeah, agreed..